# Open set is complex numbers

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I want to show that each of the inequalities $(1): Re(z)>0$ and $|z+z^2|<1$ defines an open set in $C$. I showed that $|z|<1$ is open. I tried to apply any inequality like triangle inequality but did not work.
I appreciate any help in this regard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every continuous function $\eta\colon\mathbb{C}\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ and every open subset $A$ of $\mathbb R$, $\eta^{-1}(A)$ is an open subset of $\mathbb C$. So, consider the functions $\operatorname{Re}$ and $f(z)=\lvert z+z^2\rvert$.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It is a well known statement in topology. So, since Re $z > 0$ and $|z+z^2|<1$ are open sets in $R$, the functions define an open set in $C$?

Comment: The sets $(0,\infty)$ and $(-\infty,1)$ are open sets. Therefore, $\operatorname{Re}^{-1}\bigl((0,\infty)\bigr)$ and $f^{-1}\bigl((-\infty,1)\bigr)$ are open subsets of $\mathbb C$.